# Precompile header issue

Tags: visual-c++, precompiled-headers

I added `Pre.h` to `EngineWindow.cpp` but
`EngineWindow.h` does not recognize `Pre.h`

I did this the same way in another project, but there were no problems there.

Pre.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <EngineBase\Pre.h>
#include <EngineBase\EngineMath.h>

#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <list>
#include <string>
```

EngineWindow.cpp:

```
#include "Pre.h"
#include "EngineWindow.h"

EngineWindow::EngineWindow()
{
}

EngineWindow::~EngineWindow()
{
}
```

EngineWindow.h:

```
 #pragma once

class EngineWindow 
{
public:
    // constrcuter destructer
    EngineWindow();
    ~EngineWindow();

    // constrcuter destructer
    EngineWindow(const EngineWindow& _Other) = delete;
    EngineWindow(EngineWindow&& _Other) noexcept = delete;
    EngineWindow& operator=(const EngineWindow& _Other) = delete;
    EngineWindow& operator=(EngineWindow&& _Other) noexcept = delete;

    void OpenWindow();
    void MessageLoop();

    void SetHinstance(HINSTANCE _HInst)
    {
        HInst = _HInst;
    }
    HINSTANCE HInst;
    HWND Hwnd;

    std::string WindowTitle = "Title"; //error
private:
    static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
    void Register();
    void Create();

};
```

`std::string WindowTitle = "Title";` in this part

> Error C2039: 'string': is not a member of 'std'

`Pre.h` includes `<string>`, but why does an error appear?

Comment: `_Other` is illegal (underscore followed by capital; those identifiers are reserved for the implementation). Just delete it, it's pointless there anyway.

Comment: Your project only contains those 3 files ? Or is possible that EngineWindow.h is included in another file which goes through the compiler first ?